# UITableView How to remove Swipe action after performing action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented following actions in the UITableView

```
 @available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {



    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: createLeftSwipeActionList(indexPath: indexPath))
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

    return configuration
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: createRightSwipeActionList(indexPath: indexPath))
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

    return configuration
}
```

But when I swipe row and it shows the action buttons, and when I click
that Swipe Action it triggers my action that I wanted, but it never hides it.

Please let me know how to hide action once it is performed?  Thanks

Comment: Can you please try by reloading the swiped index path with tableView.reloadRows(at: [#IndexPathObject], with: .automatic)

Comment: In the completion handler of the action call `tableView.isEditing = false`

Comment: I am removing that row on action, but the row gets removed but not that action. it stays there